# Installation of ns-allinone2.34 in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: installation, protocol

I need to install ns-allinone 2.34 in order to implement leach protocol. I followed all the steps of installation when I write `./install` in the terminal I got this result:

```
Warning: tclStubInit.c may be out of date. 
Developers may want to run "make genstubs" to regenerate. 
This warning can be safely ignored, do not report as a bug! 
Installing libtcl8.4.a to /home/rain/ns-allinone-2.34/lib/ 
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/rain/ns-allinone-2.34/lib/#inst.6373#': Permission denied 
rm: cannot remove '/home/rain/ns-allinone-2.34/lib/libtcl8.4.a': Permission denied 
mv: cannot stat '/home/rain/ns-allinone-2.34/lib/#inst.6373#': No such file or directory 
ranlib: could not create temporary file whilst writing archive: No more archived files 
make: *** [install-binaries] Error 1 
tcl8.4.18 installation failed. 
Tcl is not part of the ns project. Please see www.Scriptics.com 
to see if they have a fix for your platform.
```

Even when I enter *"ns"* the result: `command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line which includes "cp: cannot create regular file" may be trying to create a filename with illegal characters. I don't think both the number sign and colon (# and :) can be used in a file name, and it looks like the space in the name may also screw with things. If there is an alternative to using this filename through some installation configuration, I would start by trying that.